# how to include header files more clearly in C++

Tags: c++, c, header-files

In C++, I have some header files such as: `Base.h`, and some classes using `Base.h`:

```
//OtherBase1.h
#include "Base.h"
class OtherBase1{
    // something goes here
};

//OtherBase2.h
#include "Base.h"
class OtherBase2{
    // something goes here
};
```

And in `main.cpp`, I can only use one of those two `OtherBase` classes because of duplicate header. If I want to use both classes, in `OtherBase2.h` I have to `#include "OtherBase1.h"` instead of `#include "Base.h"`. Sometimes, I just want to use `OtherBase2.h` and not `OtherBase1.h`, so I think it's really weird to include `OtherBase1.h` in `OtherBase2.h`. What do I do to avoid this situation and what's the best practice for including header file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should be using [include guards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) in `Base.h`.

An example:

```
// Base.h
#ifndef BASE_H
#define BASE_H

// Base.h contents...

#endif // BASE_H
```

This will prevent multiple-inclusion of `Base.h`, and you can use both `OtherBase` headers. The `OtherBase` headers could also use include guards.

The constants themselves can also be useful for the conditional compilation of code based on the availability of the API defined in a certain header.

**Alternative:** `#pragma once`

Note that `#pragma once` can be used to accomplish the same thing, without some of the problems associated with user-created `#define` constants, e.g. name-collisions, and the minor annoyances of occasionally typing `#ifdef` instead of `#ifndef`, or neglecting to close the condition.

`#pragma once` is usually available but include guards are always available. In fact you'll often see code of the form:

```
// Base.h
#pragma once

#ifndef BASE_H
#define BASE_H

// Base.h contents...

#endif // BASE_H
```

Comment: +1. Note that on most compilers you can also just use `#pragma once` at the top of the header file for the same effect.

Answer (score 4):

You have to use header guards to avoid duplication.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard

For example in your `Base.h` add following:

```
#ifndef BASE_H_
#define BASE_H_

// stuff in Base.h

#endif
```

See this SO question for heard guard formats

[#include header guard format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/314983/include-header-guard-format)

Comment: All symbols starting with double underscores, and those starting with an underscore followed by an uppercase character are reserved by the implementation. You should use `#ifndef BASE_H__` instead.

Comment: @Prætorian, +1, thanks for reminding that, I have edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: @Prætorian: Names *containing* a double underscore are reserved. `BASE_H` or `BASE_H_` are fine, but not `BASE_H__`.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid having problems related to importing the same header file more than once, you can use the preprocessor to guard against that. The usual way of doing this is by adding these bits to `Base.h`:

```
#ifndef BASE_H_CONSTANT
#define BASE_H_CONSTANT

// Stick the actual contents of Base.h here

#endif
```