# I get a "struct type redefinition" error when trying to build project

Tags: c++, struct

I'm building a small game engine and I have created two structs in my Graphics.h file. But when I try to build the project I get a "struct" type redefinition error on both my structs.

When googling this error many peoples problem seem to be that they didn't use include guards and got a circular dependency, or that they actually did do a redefinition of their struct in the .cpp file.

I was using `"pragma once"` in my header file and I thought that maybe `#pragma once` caused the problem some way, so I tried using include guards instead but my redefinition errors did not go away.

When looking at my .h and .cpp files I personally do not see any redefinitions what so ever. I have also tried cleaning and rebuilding the project, without success.

Down below is my Graphics.h where the two structs "Vertex" and "ObjectConstants" is defined.

```
 #pragma once

struct Vertex {
    DirectX::XMFLOAT3 Pos;
    DirectX::XMFLOAT4 Color;
};

struct ObjectConstants {
    DirectX::XMFLOAT4X4 WorldViewProj = MathHelper::Identity4x4();
};

class Graphics {
public:
    void Update(const Timer& gt);
private:
    void BoxGeometry();
private:
    std::unique_ptr<UBuffer<ObjectConstants>> mObjectCB = nullptr;
};
```

And my Graphics.cpp where I use these structs:

```
#include "Graphics.h"

using namespace DirectX;

void Graphics::Update(const Timer& gt) {
    ObjectConstants objConstants;
    XMStoreFloat4x4(&objConstants.WorldViewProj, XMMatrixTranspose(worldViewProj));
    mObjectCB->CopyData(0, objConstants);
}

void Graphics::BoxGeometry() {
    std::array<Vertex, 8> vertices =
    {
        Vertex({ XMFLOAT3(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f), XMFLOAT4(Colors::White) }),
        Vertex({ XMFLOAT3(-1.0f, +1.0f, -1.0f), XMFLOAT4(Colors::Black) }),
        Vertex({ XMFLOAT3(+1.0f, +1.0f, -1.0f), XMFLOAT4(Colors::Red) }),
        Vertex({ XMFLOAT3(+1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f), XMFLOAT4(Colors::Green) }),
        Vertex({ XMFLOAT3(-1.0f, -1.0f, +1.0f), XMFLOAT4(Colors::Blue) }),
        Vertex({ XMFLOAT3(-1.0f, +1.0f, +1.0f), XMFLOAT4(Colors::Yellow) }),
        Vertex({ XMFLOAT3(+1.0f, +1.0f, +1.0f), XMFLOAT4(Colors::Cyan) }),
        Vertex({ XMFLOAT3(+1.0f, -1.0f, +1.0f), XMFLOAT4(Colors::Magenta) })
    };
}
```

So I get the redefinition error on both my Vertex and ObjectConstant structs.
I do not see that I have redefined my structs anywhere (since the only place I use the structs are in the two methods provided in the Graphics class) and all my header files are using include guards.

If anyone can help me solve this problem I would appreciate it.
Thanks.

Edit:
The errors I get is the following:

Error [C2011](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-1/compiler-error-c2011?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(C2011)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=vs-2019)    'Vertex': 'struct' type redefinition File: Graphics.h Line: 3

Error   [C2011](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-1/compiler-error-c2011?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(C2011)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=vs-2019)  'ObjectConstants': 'struct' type redefinition File: Graphics.h Line: 8

The compiler I am using is the msvc compiler. I am using VS 2019.

Comment: What is  the  exact error you're getting? Have you tried  renaming the struct and seeing if the error follows the new names?

Comment: Is the compiler telling you where the two definitions are?

Comment: out of curiosity, what compiler? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12148348/pragma-once-compilers-support

Comment: You are missing semicolon after declaration of `class Graphics`, Generally you should provide a [mcve] that reproduces your problem please.

Comment: Add the missing semicolon then try again. When pasting error messages the lines they appear on are also important, so you should copy/paste as much of the error that makes sense. Basically if you end up with a 200 line template error message you don't want all of that, but the first few lines are important.

Comment: I have updated the question to try and answer your questions.                                            @RetiredNinja If I rename the structs the error do follow the new names when trying to rebuild

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I have added that semicolon now, thanks. With the code provided in my question I am able to reproduce the error on my machine.

Comment: @Jacce I am wondering if you re-do  all of this by putting it in the header and using your namespace, and place `using namespace DirectX`  just where needed, ie. in functions where required, what will  happen then? Also above can not be solved in isolation, you are not showing as where do you include directX and the code where this is used, etc ...